# Get Posts ordered by a date custom meta field

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, query, meta-query

I have created a meta field for a custom post type. This is a date field that will always be YYYY-MM-DD. There could be 100s of posts so i cant query them all and sort afterwards. I need to be able to perform a query to get 5 posts ordered by the date, for example, upcoming items. This will display 5 posts that are in the future.

I have looked into it and i can see that it is possible to provide 
`orderby=meta_value` combined with `metakey=date` to do this, but it doesnt treat the date as a date object. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You'll need to do a `meta_query`, there are really plenty of info regarding this on this site. I know I have done a lot of answers on this. Have you actually checked the related posts in the sidebar of this very post

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `'orderby'    => 'meta_value','meta_key'  => 'event-date-start'`